# How to skip links in pagination..?

Tags: javascript, php, pagination

I am developing an application in core PHP, and I've to implement pagination in one of the pages, I've implemented virtually everything but I don't know how to hide some of the pagination links, if the number of pages is quite high. The below image will give you a better idea about what I want.

[image: As you can see here between page number 8 and 18, some links have been skipped]

> As you can see between page number 8 and 18, some links have been
>   skipped.

**I am not asking for some code or detailed logic, an overview or an abstract algorithm would suffice!**

Comment: The answer will depend primarily on how you created your pagination.

Comment: It won't be possible for me to disclose the code, as it's quite long, isn't there some "universal" way that can help to decide which links to skip?

Comment: It all depends on you. You can leave first and last three, you can leave first ten and last two.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen my fellows suggest using WordPress. Since you are not mentioning it however, I will try to provide a standardized answer.

It all depends on the way you created your pagination, but a rough guess (according to your design) would be:

1. After segmenting your data into pages, get the count of the number of pages.
2. Compare that count to a static number (the number of pages you want to display.
3. If the number is less or equal, you won't need to do anything, just let it all load up.
4. If not, you will proceed by loading up the said links within a range. According to your image, you want to have 11 page links displaying in total. Now it gets harder.
5. You will need to logically divide your pages into logic ensembles. Thus if you click for example on page 5, you will still see the same thing, except the fact that the 5th link shows as clicked. The groups can be divided by modulo 11 in your case, then load the ones as 0 < x%11 < 9, then load a link (the ...) that will take you to the next page in the sequence, then print the two last pages' links. If you want to go for simplicity, just load the page you're in as 1st, then load the logical sequence. It will be up to you.

Quick note: Point 5 will be intricate since you will need to apply it recursively. Some points I've mentioned in it might not be an optimal way, or it might feel a bit clunky, but you get the general idea. You can adjust it as needed